# How to call client-side object in server-side code in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net

How can we call an object from client side on the server side, c# calling an input object, for instance? In classic asp.NET I would just id the object and put the `runat='server'` property.

Comment: can you be more specific what you are trying to do ?

Comment: You weren't "calling a client side object". You just thought you were. In actuality you were manipulating a server side control that rendered to HTML upon completion of the request. Now you're probably using MVC - you don't  have controls to deal with. Instead, you pass a View Model to your View from the Controller. If the page has already been sent to the client, you either do a form submit or do some sort of call to the server (such as AJAX or web sockets) if you need to obtain some information from the server.